# Pogramatically added constraint works in reverse

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

Adding the following bottom constraint and setting the constant to -100 seems to works in complete reverse than when i add that constant in the constraint in the Storyboard.

Specifically, this will push the view 100 units above the bottom part of the controller whereas the expected behaviour is to make it go 100 units lower. Im most likely making a very silly mistake but i just cant see it right now.

```
    func setUp(parentController: UIViewController){

        self.parentController = parentController;

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pullUpViewHeight).isActive = true

        self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR = self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentController.view.bottomAnchor)
        self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR!.isActive = true;
        self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR!.constant = -100

    }
```

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: `a-b` and `b-a` are additive inverses of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always depends on the participating views' / anchors' order. Switch `parentController.view.bottomAnchor` and `self.bottomAnchor` when setting up the constraint and you're good to go (because what you are trying to achieve is that the `parentController`'s view's bottom is equal to the view's bottom minus 100 points).

```
self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR = parentController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
```

You can set the constant immediately when creating the constraint btw:

```
self.pullUpViewBottomCSTR = parentController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -100)
```

Answer (score 1):

It always baffled me that does it matter if I swap the views when I'm writing constraints or not. The answer is, sometimes it matters, sometimes it doesn't.

In general:

Imagine you have ViewA & ViewB, and you set a constraint between them with **`0`**. They are glued together. For this case the order of constraining the views doesn't matter.

ViewA & ViewB, you set a constraint between them with **`20`**. They are **not** glued together. There is some **space** between them. Do you want ViewA stand firm and move/push ViewB or do you want ViewB to stand firm and make ViewA move? For that reason it matters to which you're adding the constraint onto.

If it doesn't work the first time then I just switch the constraint and add it onto the other view and then it works fine.

Comment: Actually you do not add the constraint to one of the participating views but their common ancestor.

Comment: correct, but still it matters to how you constrain two subviews to each other.